# Select values from one column of one table that are part of a different column and table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one table for users (`user_id`, `name`,...) and one for groups (`group_id`, `description`,...). The `description` contains a string with all users in that specific group (`user1`, `user2`...). There are users who do not belong to any group.

I want to get all users that are in a group. I already tried the `LIKE` statement but it didn't work. It looked like this:

```
Select users.name
FROM users, groups
WHERE users.name LIKE '%' + groups.description + '%'
```

It did work when I insert one specific user name (...`LIKE '%'"user1"'%'`)

Comment: _"it didn't work"_ is not a problem description. What happened? Why was that wrong? Show input data, desired results, and current wrong results. Anyway, looks to me like your `LIKE` operands are the wrong way around.

Comment: Fix your data structure!  You should have a table called `UserGroups` with one row per user and per group.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very unclear due to the lack of sample data and results. But if `groups.description` contains one or more user names, then your `LIKE` operands are the wrong way around. To check whether a user name is in the group's string list of users, you'd need `groups.description like '%' + users.name + '%'`

Then you should start using proper SQL joins, not the error-prone pre-1992 syntax, so that'll be:

```
select
    users.name,
    groups.group_id
from users
inner join groups on groups.description like '%' + users.name + '%';
```

This will return a list of users and the group(s) to which they belong... If you're lucky. Because this is a very brittle design. Here's a thought experiment: what if some users have names that are substrings of other users' names, but those users don't belong to the same groups?

Either way, you should be using a separate table that maps users to groups, for proper normalisation and far easier/more maintainable queries.

Comment: I think that this solution work sooo slooow and incorrect. If the author has 2 users, first name 'Abyr' and second name 'Abyrvalg', and he will execute query like `select
    users.name,
    groups.group_id
from users
inner join groups on groups.description like '%' + 'Abyr' + '%';`, he gets the groups of the second user, too.

Comment: @KadafiVSC You will note on re-reading that I already anticipated that exact problem. I'm just working within the poor design the OP described. Complain to them about their design - or if you know a way to magically fix all the problems with a query alone, then post it. Either way, it's not my problem. This answers the question they asked and goes beyond that to suggest better ways; I don't know what more you expect.

Comment: Yes, i know the correct solution - to use normalization :)

Comment: Sorry, i really didn't read your message, only saw the query :(

Comment: Add a separator after users.name, `'%' + users.name + ',' + '%';` - i think it will work.

Comment: @KadafiVSC - I believe this still won't work... you're forgetting the last name that might not end on a comma. I guess the workaround of that would be: `ON (ISNULL(groups.description,'') + ',' ) like '%' + users.name + ',' + '%'`  
However, I believe my answer might be better than this altogether.

Answer (score 1):

The following Table-valued function might be of use here:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnSplitStrings]
(
    @List       NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Delimiter  NVARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS

    RETURN (SELECT Number = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Number),
        Item FROM (SELECT Number, Item = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@List, Number, 
        CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @List + @Delimiter, Number) - Number)))
    FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s1.[object_id])
        FROM sys.all_objects AS s1 CROSS APPLY sys.all_objects) AS n(Number)
    WHERE Number <= CONVERT(INT, LEN(@List))
        AND SUBSTRING(@Delimiter + @List, Number, 1) = @Delimiter
    ) AS y);
```

This function will split a certain column and return a new row for each value.

Here is an example of how to use it:

```
SELECT
      g.group_id,
      f.item
FROM groups g
CROSS APPLY dbo.fnSplitStrings(g.Description, ', ') AS f

--You could even join the actual users if necessary
SELECT
      g.group_id,
      f.item,
      u.user_id
FROM groups g
CROSS APPLY dbo.fnSplitStrings(g.Description, ', ') AS f
INNER JOIN users u ON u.name = f.item
```

If anything else is unclear, just leave a comment.

Comment: This is a safer solution than the naive one the OP and myself gave, which at least mitigates one of the main pitfalls created by their chosen design: the danger of users having names that are substrings of other users'. So, +1. However, having to write code to split/join fields is always an indication of the wrong design IMO. (except when parsing multi-value parameters from SSRS or such, I suppose)

Comment: @underscore_d - You're right. This is something I've used to split email addresses that were separated by `;` in a single column to form a list of unique addresses.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 tables, 'Users' and 'Groups', you create third table, 'UsersInGroups', which contains 2 fields: 'id_user' and 'id_group'. Make a selection:

```
select u.name from Users u
join UsersInGroups gu on u.user_id = gu.user_id
join Groups g on gu.group_id = g.group_id
where g.name = 'GroupName' --or g.group_id = YourId
```